# mysqli query statement does not work

Tags: php, search

I have written a mysqli statement for advanced search of my website. the generated query does not work. here is the generated query:

```
 SELECT title, stars, pic_main, id, province FROM ads WHERE 'province' = 8 AND( title LIKE %شریف% OR content LIKE %شریف% OR keywords LIKE %شریف% OR title LIKE %شریف%)
```

And here is the code that I use to execute the query:

```
if($transorder = $site_db->query($statement))
{
    echo "True";
    $i=0;
    while($row_obj = $transorder->fetch_object())
    {
        $item[$i]['id'] = $row_obj->id;
        $item[$i]['pic_main'] = $row_obj->pic_main;
        $item[$i]['title'] = $row_obj->title;
        $item[$i]['province'] = $row_obj->province;
        $item[$i]['stars'] = $row_obj->stars;       
        $i++;
    }
}
else
{
    echo "False";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around text in your LIKE statements, also I notice you are using title 2 times. If you use single quote (province), MySQL might expect you are comparing the String 'province' with the value `8` you should use ` around the `'province'`:

```
 SELECT title, stars, pic_main, id, province 
 FROM ads 
 WHERE `province` = 8 
       AND ( title LIKE '%شریف%' 
             OR content LIKE '%شریف%' 
             OR keywords LIKE '%شریف%' 
             OR title LIKE '%شریف%')
```

To find out what error MySQL is returning you can use `echo $site_db->error;`.

**The Solution was**

```
$site_con->set_charset("utf8");
```

Because of the use of the use of none default characters of the MySQL connection. So the connection should be set to `utf8`

Comment: now my question is that, is this query well enough to perform a search operation? because it yields no result

Comment: You can alwasy try to do `$site_db->error` to see what error is returned.

Comment: it shows no error....and also no result....while there is an item in db to matched...strange

Comment: can you please explain a bit about ' and "

Comment: the `\`` is used for columns. A single quote `'` and double quote `"`  is used for text. If you use `'province'=8` you compare the string with an number. Which will always return false because they do not match. If you do `\`province\`=8` it will compare the column `province` with 8.

Comment: it is very strange because adding your suggestion, it still fails to operate and yield no result

Comment: Maybe add this before all: `$site_con->set_charset("utf8");` because your using non standard utf-8 characters?